# Python RPi.GPIO Button Activates Relay - Needs to address button hold

Tags: python, arduino, gpio

I've written some code to turn a relay on and off when a button is pressed. When I press the button once, all is right with the world and the relay turns on with the first press, and off with the second press, etc. My problem is that when I hold the button down, the relay just turns on and off and on and off until the button is let up. This is not a desired result. I only want the relay to turn on once for each press.

Here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
# GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)

print "GPIO STATE OF PIN 17"
print GPIO.input(17)
print "GPIO STATE OF PIN 22"
print GPIO.input(22)

# MAKE SURE SOLENOID IS OFF
solenoid = "OFF"
GPIO.output(17,True)

print "Push button to open and close solenoid."

while True:
input_state = GPIO.input(22)
if input_state == False and solenoid == "ON":
    print('SOLENOID OFF')
    solenoid = "OFF"
    GPIO.output(17,True)
    time.sleep(0.2)
elif input_state == False and solenoid == "OFF":
    print('SOLENOID ON')
    solenoid = "ON"
    GPIO.output(17,False)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

How can I modify this code to achieve my desired result.

Best,

Bryan

Comment: What does `input_state` represent physically? Is it that the button is being pressed?

Answer (score 0):

I found a resolution to my issue...

GPIO.wait_for_edge(22, GPIO.RISING)

Was added to while loop:

```
while True:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(22, GPIO.RISING)
    input_state = GPIO.input(22)
    if input_state == False and solenoid == "ON":
        print('SOLENOID OFF')
        solenoid = "OFF"
        GPIO.output(17,True)
       time.sleep(0.2)
    elif input_state == False and solenoid == "OFF":
        print('SOLENOID ON')
        solenoid = "ON"
        GPIO.output(17,False)
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

wait_for_edge() function

The wait_for_edge() function is designed to block execution of your program until an edge is detected. In other words, the example above that waits for a button press could be rewritten as:
GPIO.wait_for_edge(channel, GPIO.RISING)
Note that you can detect edges of type GPIO.RISING, GPIO.FALLING or GPIO.BOTH. The advantage of doing it this way is that it uses a negligible amount of CPU, so there is plenty left for other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the second elif:

```
if input_state == False and solenoid == "ON":
    print('SOLENOID OFF')
    solenoid = "OFF"
    GPIO.output(17,True)
    time.sleep(0.2)
elif input_state == False and solenoid == "OFF":
    print('SOLENOID ON')
    solenoid = "ON"
    GPIO.output(17,False)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Specifically, `input_state == False` should be `input_state == True`, otherwise whenever `input_state` is False, you'll keep toggling `solenoid` back and forth between "ON" and "OFF".

Edit: I see now that you're trying to make it toggle once when you push the button. In that case, you should remove the input_state check entirely and just use the rising edge function. (My above code will turn on the relay while the button is held, and turn it off when it is released).

Comment: For some reason my relay behaves in reverse, which is why input_state == False otherwise i'd set it to true.

Comment: @evolution9 You're comparing the same thing in both cases, which doesn't make sense. The two clauses of the if need to be different, otherwise you'll alternate between them in the while loop.

Comment: @evolution9, see my edit, I thought you wanted the relay to be on while the button was held, but I see you want it to toggle instead. You shouldn't need to check input_state at all in this case.